# Measurable subgroups.

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, measure-theory, haar-measure

Let $G$ be a compact connected topological group and let $H$ be a subgroup of $G$. Suppose that $H$ is measurable with respect to the normalised Haar measure $\mu$ on $G$. Do we necessarily have $\mu(H)=0$ or $\mu(H)=1$?

Maybe this is well--known, I ask it just out of curiosity. The question is related to [this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/22934/a-question-of-erds-on-equidistribution) one: If you provide a measurable subgroup $H$ of $\mathbb R/\mathbb Z$ of measure not 0 or 1, then the characteristic function of $H$ violates the conjecture stated there.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Don't we still have this:  if $A$ is measurable of positive measure, then $A A^{-1}$ contains a neighborhood of the identity...?  So: a measurable subgroup of positive measure itself contains a neighborhood of the identity, and thus by connectedness is all of $G$.

Comment: If that is true (it seems like a nontrivial statement, but I'm willing to believe) the story ends here.


Comment: I'm certain that this is in Hewitt+Ross volume 1, but I don't have a copy handy to check.  I'm not sure of a more modern textbook reference...

Comment: This is true for any locally compact second countable group. This is proven e.g. in the appendices at the end of Zimmer book "Ergodic theory and semi-simple Lie groups". The proof is not very different from the proof for the group R of real numbers, that you can find in many textbooks.

Comment: For future reference, this is known as [Steinhaus's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steinhaus_theorem).  The wikipedia page gives some links to elementary proofs: in particular this holds for any locally compact group.